# DB connection pool in Standalone Axis2?

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, connection-pooling

For my services in production environment I always set up DB connections pool in Tomcat's `context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="256" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
    username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://host:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
/>
```

Then later in my service I use:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB");
Connection db = ds.getConnection();
```

For development I want to run Axis2 standalone - is there a way how I could set up somewhere DB connections pool in Axis as well so I would not need to modify service code and use it the same way as with Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have different context.xml files for different environments.

e.g.

```
context_DEV.xml
context_UAT.xml
context_PROD.xml
```

and then use a symlink to point to the correct one.

e.g.

```
context.xml -> context_DEV.xml
```

Also, see [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg33463.html) which recommends using a servlet container (such as Tomcat) rather than axis2 standalone server for stability.

Comment: But Axis runs within a servlet container, such as Tomcat, Weblogic, Jetty or WebSphere. You can't run it standalone.

Comment: If you download Standard Binary Distribution you can run Axis2 as a Standalone Server: http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_3/installationguide.html#standalone